# rhc setup not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools

I tried the following command `rhc setup` and following message is displayed

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/ssh (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:72:in `<class:Wizard>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in `<module:RHC>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/commands/app.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/commands.rb:139:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/commands.rb:138:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/commands.rb:138:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/lib/rhc/cli.rb:35:in `start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.8.9/bin/rhc:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rhc setup gives error \`no such file dl/import\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)

Answer (score 1):

periodically updating to the latest version of `rhc` is a good idea as well:

```
sudo gem update rhc
```

It should pull `net-ssh` in as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Updating net-ssh to 2.9.3.beta1, as cremno suggested in this comment, resolved my problem and a few other people as well.

```
$ gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
```

this answer is from: [rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This below code did the trick

```
sudo gem install net-ssh
```