# rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import`

Tags: ruby, openshift

I'm installing openshift client tools as described: https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools.
On step 'Setting up Your Machine' I got error:

> rhc setup
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>   : cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)

Full stack trace:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in `<module:RHC>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.1/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I found same problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/supmua/hPyTTamhTyc
It's suggest to replace DL with Fiddle.

How I can get working rhc?

Comment: I can't and won't test it, but try installing [net-ssh-2.9.3.beta1](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/versions/2.9.3.beta1). [This commit](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/commit/33f8a46d2891ee5de4c55e1bf8b1b04d8d8c5133) added support for fiddle.

Comment: Nothing has ever worked smoothly with Ruby ever since I used it 3 years ago. Every single time some or the other error due to version problems. Open shift recommends installing latest! Extremely frustrating!

Comment: I can´t understand. It worked, thanks

Comment: It did not work for me, trying with all suggested here; old versions from ruby, net-ssh, newer, update... but I still cannot make this setup work.

Comment: I found out that the latest rhc version 1.38.4 declares dependency to net-ssh <=2.9.2 so it doesn't want to run with net-ssh-2.9.3.beta1. I reverted to rhc version 1.37.1 which ran successfully using net-ssh-2.9.3.beta1.

Comment: **dl has been removed from ruby**... someone who knows ruby is requested to **fork rhc and use fiddle** instead.. 
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L148-L149

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openshift and net-ssh incompatibility? (2.9.3-beta1 vs 2.9.2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906673/openshift-and-net-ssh-incompatibility-2-9-3-beta1-vs-2-9-2)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Updating net-ssh to 2.9.3.beta1, as [cremno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231385/cremno) suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import#comment46054598_28896733), resolved my problem.

```
gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
```

Before that, I tried `gem install net-ssh`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I had the same issue. However, you need to GEM install 2.9.3beta1, not 2.5.3, so the command should be gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1

Comment: I've trqed to update to  2.9.3.beta1, tried to 2.10.1.rc1. Nothing seems to help =(

Comment: It didn't work for me as well. Eventually I used findstr under the ruby gems directory and manually changed all dl usages to fiddle.
For _Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb_ I changed `dl` to `fiddle` in lines 1, 6 & 7, I also changed `Dl` to `Fiddle` in lines 40, 42, 44, 164, 176, 180 & 184.
I also use Highline so I had to do the same in file _Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\highline-1.6.19\lib\highline\system_extensions.rb_, lines 76 & 79.

Comment: The issue is with Ruby 2.2.2. Downgrade to Ruby to 2.1.6 and net-ssh to 2.9.2  [Issue details in Github](https://github.com/openshift/rhc/issues/682). Even if rhc installs with 2.9.3.beta1, at the time of ssh connection to the app, it won't work.  It will complain something about: Could not parse PKey: no start line

Comment: it didn't work for me :(
C:\>rhc setup
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
 `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
      
     .........

        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'

Comment: This didn't work for me. I installed Ruby 1.9.3 and re-installed rhc, that worked.

Comment: I had installed `2.2.4` version but the above answer doesn't work for that. Then i installed `2.1.6` version and above answer worked for that.

Comment: it looks this problem is manifestation of hardcore requirement on net-ssh version <= 2.9.0<br> net-ssh 3.* have solved this problem... we just need to use net-ssh with rhc see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35935384/2382629

Answer (score 49):

I ran into this problem when I used the latest version of Ruby (currently 2.2.1) as stated on the OpenShift setup instructions. I fixed it by:

1. Installing Ruby 1.9.3
2. Re-running "gem install rhc"

After that, I was able to run "rhc setup" without any issue.

Comment: gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1 works, no need to reinstalling ruby to older version

Comment: as Hoto said, gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1 works. don't revert to 1.9.3

Comment: net-ssh -v2.9.3beta1 will gives error when taking snapshots and tail

Comment: Same issue here and I downgraded Ruby from 2.2 to 1.9.3 and it worked

Comment: I confirm the solution of using ruby 1.9.3. I tried with the latest 2.2.x and it failed. I uninstalled it, installer 1.9.3, ran `gem install rhc` again then `rhc setup` again and things now work fine.

Comment: Actually installing any previous version than 2.2 of ruby resolves the issue. In my case, I'm using 2.1.7 and it works

Answer (score 17):

If you are running **Windows 10** Pro x64, try installing `Ruby` [2.1.8 (x64)](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) with [Git Version 2.7.0](http://www.git-scm.com/download/win). This will surely allow you to run `rhc setup` as it did happened with me. Earlier I had a problem running & installing latest version of `Ruby 2.2.4 (x64)` but when I downgraded to ruby version `2.1.8 (x64)` I was able to run `rhc setup` and configure `OpenShift client tools`on Windows. See the image for Ruby version I'm using - `ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x64-mingw32]`

[image]

[Read here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools) for getting started to `OpenShift client tools` on windows.

Comment: This seems to work, but I do see `$ rhc setup` -->  `DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle` when I run the setup.

Comment: This seems to be a fail.  When I go to `$ rhc setup` I get down to the point where I type in my password, hit return, then the system just hangs there.  No error message, no feedback, just no function.  This whole RHC thing from OpenShift is terrible.

Answer (score 11):

Use the **RHC tested** Ruby version instead of the latest. As of today it is [1.9.3-p194](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives)

Comment: how did you know the RHC tested ruby version ?

Comment: Downgrading to version 1.9.3-p194 worked for me. Thanks @reversiblean

Answer (score 1):

Try using/installing a lower version of ruby after uninstalling the 2,2,0 because some windows version conflict with ruby version you are using. I tried 2.2.3 and then lowered to 2.2.0 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error, and none of the solutions worked for me. In a last attempt, I installed the Ruby 1.9.3-p551 version and the rhc setup went smoothly. I use a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64. I installed Ruby 2.1.8 (x64) with Git Version 2.7.2. Rhc was installed successfully. However, "rhc snapshot save ..." command had problem with net-ssh. However, after restarting windows 10 the errors was gone.

Remember to try reboot your windows.

Comment: By the way, I also have to move ruby to C: (windows root drive) instead of D: drive (my software drive). OR the c: user drive. It was weird but it did matter.

Comment: I finally realized it is because I am running pageant (putty key management). It will cause ”Creation of file mapping failed with error: 998 (Net::SSH::Exception)“. It was not about C drive or D drive or rebooting the computer. (Rebooting my computer will stop pageant service.