# rhc setup on Windows shows 'require' errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, cloud, redhat

I am trying to setup rhc tools on a newly installed Windows 8.1 Pro x64. I already have git, ruby and successfully installed the rhc gem.

The tutorial I used - https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools

I've used rhc tools on Ubuntu and never on Windows, and I have no idea what the error means.

Doing rhc setup shows the following error:

```
>rb --version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
>git --version
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
>rhc setup
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' : cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54 :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in `<module:RHC>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

**Edit:**

The following post solves the problem - [rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)
It seems that there is also a bug reported for this - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1201844

For windows:

```
gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
```

Comment: You are probably missing some dependencies. Please, take a look to openshift website for any available info.

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of experience running Ruby on Windows, but finally I (and others) came up to conclusion that it's not possible to run some gems without errors on Windows at the moment.

You can run and install one gem, but you'll get an error in another gem. Finally I tired fixing them.

But good news is that you can use Vagrant + VirtualBox + Rails on Windows. You may want to read [my blog post about that](https://putshello.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/easy-rails-with-vagrant-virtualbox-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem too. you are using "Ruby 2.2.0". Please use 1.9.3 version instead. It'll work like a charm