# Openshift - "Unable to connect to gear" when running: rhc show-app <app> --gear quota

Tags: openshift, redhat

I created an app called "world" following the instructions from:
https://blog.openshift.com/12-tips-for-hosting-wordpress-on-openshift/.

It's a hosted Wordpress blog, with PHP 5.4 scalable up to 1GB, with a Web Load Balancer and MySQL 5.5.

Everytime I try to check for the space used, I get the same error.

```
rhc show-app world --gears quota

Unable to connect to gear 54d48383fcf933f91f0000aa@54d48383fcf933f91f0000aa-laurapons.rhcloud.com
Unable to connect to gear 54d48383fcf933f91f0000a9@world-laurapons.rhcloud.com
Gear                     Cartridges           Used Limit
------------------------ ------------------- ----- -----
54d48383fcf933f91f0000aa mysql-5.5           error  1 GB
54d48383fcf933f91f0000a9 haproxy-1.4 php-5.4 error  1 GB
```

I tried to restart the application (using restart and stop&start commands) but nothing seems to work.

I am also facing some other connection problems (probably related to the same issue):
I have the same problem when trying to clone the application with **git clone**:

```
ssh: connect to host world-laurapons.rhcloud.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

And also with the **rhc port-forward world**

I copied the URL for git clone from the openshift online dashboard, and I can open the wordpress blog and see all the information, but somehow, I'm unable to access to the data.

I have already created a default Public Key and 2 authorisations (one to access through the browser and the other to access through RHC)...

What should I try?
How can I get the usage?
Do I need to set up anything else?

I am stuck... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rhc with some ruby version will have issue with pageant (putty). I closed pageant, ran again rhc command then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your SSH key is not working properly. Make sure you installed your keys and that they are working. Try running 'rhc setup'. If that still doesn't work try

```
ssh -vvv 54d48383fcf933f91f0000a9@world-laurapons.rhcloud.com
```

and look at the output.

You can also try using

```
ssh -i /path/to/your/ssh.key 54d48383fcf933f91f0000a9@world-laurapons.rhcloud.com
```

And see if that works (specifies what ssh key to use)

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and fwd, thanks. Just to mention, I've just tried it under Mac, the authorization token was expired, but after setting the pwd, everything worked.

It could be because I was trying it under Windows, and when running rhc setup I had to install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1 as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import ? After installing this package, rhc setup was working, but I couldn't access to the gears... Anyway, I will try it again with Windows, but from now I can see the gears are 10% full :) Many thanks!!