# issue with rhc setup and openshift

Tags: windows, git, openshift, openshift-client-tools

This is my first time trying out openshift or similar services and I have been running into problems with `rhc setup`.

I have installed Ruby, Git and rhc according to the documentation [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html), but when I run the `rhc setup` command in command prompt I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Richie>rhc setup
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
: cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb
:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpe
rs.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:7:in `<module:RHC>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands/
base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands/
account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands/
account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:189:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:188:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:188:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36
:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.36.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I am running Windows 7 if that makes a difference.

If someone can help me resolve this issue it would be much appreciated as I have little experience with this stuff myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rhc setup gives error \`no such file dl/import\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)

Comment: @earthdan no, this is another problem.

Answer (score 9):

Use the recommended version (1.9.3)

Comment: Thanks same here and fixed by downgrading to 1.9.3