# Not able to start the rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssh, rubygems

I am new to Ruby, am trying to setup Ruby jruby and Ruby on Rails.

I installed `bundler` and using "rails server -e qa"  command in my command prompt. I am getting:

> pageant.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import
>   (LoadError).

```
Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-3.1.6/lib/mongoid/persistence/atomic/operation.rb:74: warning: circular argument reference - field
Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadEr
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:1:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
     from D:/Ruby_WS/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
     from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
     from script/rails:6:in `require'
     from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28896733/3035830)?

Comment: Hi shivam, thanks for your answer,i tried but it's not work...

Comment: It didn't work for me as well. Eventually I used findstr under the ruby gems directory and manually changed all dl usages to fiddle.
For _Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb_ I changed `dl` to `fiddle` in lines 1, 6 & 7, I also changed `Dl` to `Fiddle` in lines 40, 42, 44, 164, 176, 180 & 184.
I also use Highline so I had to do the same in file _Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\highline-1.6.19\lib\highline\system_extensions.rb_, lines 76 & 79.