# Unable to use RHC without token

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift

I've just installed `rhc` on my laptop, and when trying to connect to my `Openshift` account with the command

```
rhc setup
```

it just stops in what looks like an endless loop after I typed in my password.

However if I use the command

```
rhc setup --token "my token"
```

it works fine. The only problem now is that everytime I have to use the `rhc` command I have to parse my token along with it.

Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

**EDIT**

How the console looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to OpenShift admin page, delete all ssh keys associated with your account. On your local machine, delete all ssh keys and tokens. Then, run `rhc setup`

I am not so sure why that happens, but I struggled with the same problem before. Maybe rhc gets confused which token to use. Running `rhc setup` fresh with no ssh keys and tokens fixed my issue. And make sure, if you have multiple rhc servers, to run `rhc use servername`

Comment: Just tried that, same result. Can't get pass the password part

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I would play with [rhc setup options](http://www.xopun.com/openshift-rhc-client-details#setup) because it looks like configuration error. i.e) You can try `rhc setup --clean`. Are you able to use rhc without providing token option after `rhc setup`?

Comment: Yea still works with `--token`. I just added an image of my console in the question.

Comment: 1. Try installing **ruby 1.9.3** instead of latest version. 2. Re-run `gem install rhc`. 3. Try `gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1` It's solution from [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28896733/2243135), but it seems a lot of people have trouble with later ruby version.

Comment: I'm already using **ruby 1.9.3** and also used the `net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1` ^^