# I upgraded my Ruby version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.4 but it throws the following error( cannot load such file -- dl/import)

Tags: ruby, watir

```
Error: IDITHarnessTest
: LoadError: cannot load such file -- dl/import
C:/Ruby224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

I searched the solution for this problem, I found a thread in stackoverflow "[rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)" in which it's instructed that installing 'gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1' would resolve my problem, I installed but the same problem persist. Even after Installing that gem, it still throws this error

```
Error: IDITHarnessTest
: LoadError: cannot load such file -- dl/import
C:/Ruby224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 51: 
 52:     if Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps.empty? then
 53:       RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.exit
=> 54:       return gem_original_require(path)
 55:     end
 56: 
 57:     # If +path+ is for a gem that has already been loaded, don't
 C:/Ruby224/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Can anyone help me to find where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this also? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35231025/4304188

Comment: Are you asking whether I have read '

If you are running Windows 10 Pro x64, try installing Ruby 2.1.8 (x64) with Git Version 2.7.0. This will surely allow you to .....'?

Comment: "it throw the error" what is "it"? what have you exaclty done? And why don't you told us about your operation system? Please make your question better first.

Comment: meier  I change my Ruby 2.1.6 to Ruby 2.2.4, then I have gotten his error. I tried with the solution which I posted above but it's not working

Comment: The more effort you are take to ask your question the better and sooner you get help. 
Please have look at:"How to ask a good question "http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem in my question, I am saying I upgraded Ruby version and have gotten this error, What else Can I say in this place?

Comment: I think this is a known issue: https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/issues/73

Comment: Orde Yes, but none of them has given the solution, One person has asked to install "gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1" But I tried this and mentioned in my Original post as well.